# selected option in dropdown with user details

Tags: angular

i have a form with a dropdown containing US states, coming from a ts file that looks like this

```
{
    "name": "Alabama",
    "abbreviation": "AL"
}, //and so on...
```

my logged user has state: "AL" and I need to display in the dropdown "Alabama" instead.

How to do this?
This is what I tried so far but I don't know how to use my states file

```
 this.vendorInformationForm = this.fb.group({
      city: [currentUser.city, Validators.maxLength(20)],
      state: [currentUser.state, [Validators.required]],
```

and this is my dropdown element

```
        <!--state-->
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="state">State</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="state" #p formControlName="state">
                  <option required *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state" [selected]="state">
                    {{state.name}}
                  </option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: what does states contains ?

Comment: {
    "name": "Alabama",
    "abbreviation": "AL"
}, //and so on...

Comment: okay, then you can try like this, [value]="state.abbreviation"

Comment: value for option should be 'state.abbreviation'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the [selected] from the option tag and set [value] like below.

```
<option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state.abbreviation">{{state.name}} 
</option>
```

Check this demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-forms-wdux4r